# Windows Phone half page Pivot

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

Does anyone know any method to get same pivot effect with 2 classic pivot pages and one page that would be half width?
I tried making custom pivot from start by making StackPanel, implementing swipe and flick but i get some bad results (bad responsivity).

Comment: What are you ultimately trying to achieve? Having multiple pivots on a page would lead to all sorts of weird usability edge cases and be very unlikely to behave in a way that was predictable to users as, if unless heavily restyled, it would behave like they would expect based on other pivots in other apps on the phone.

Comment: If I'm reading correctly between the lines, you want a *PivotPage* with two normal-width *PivotItems* and one half-widht PivotItem. Is the half of the previous normal-width Item is supposed to be visible, when user swipes to half-width PivotItem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, nesting Pivots in an application is against Windows design guidelines, so you won't find much help here.

Comment: This isn't about nesting pivots. They want two side by side.

Comment: Please post a picture with what you want because it's really not clear what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Look at Panorama - it has a bit higher level of freedom. Take a look at "500 backgrouds" app on the market. I'm not creator, i just liked panorama behavior there :)

And dBlisse is right - having more than one pivot item on the screen is bad idea.

Comment: Sorry guys i found what i want. I was trying to achieve this.
http://developer.nokia.com/Blogs/Community/2013/08/31/add-side-menus-to-an-windows-phone-application-similar-to-the-facebook-app/
Thank you for your time.